# Which tools you use in the initial brain-storming of the project requirements?

Tags: requirements

Other than pencil & paper?
I found freemind, the mapping tool very useful. 
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I like physical paper notebooks and pencils to workout ideas  :-), but some times I use [FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/).

Check this list of [Mind Mapping Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mind_mapping_software).

Answer (score 3):

Post-It notes

Whiteboard and decent coloured pens

Walls to pin the notes on to

Digital camera to capture all the work

The book Domain Driven Design :)

Answer (score 1):

I find this ([FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)) an excellent way to capture structured unstructured thoughts.  Great for brainstorming, although it doesnt cover the diagram side.

Answer (score 1):

Usualy we use writeboard. Personaly - pencil & paper. And one of most comfortable tools what I'm using for taking notes, making todo and other lists is [VIM Outliner](http://www.vimoutliner.org/). If you don't use VIM, I believe you can find any other comfortable outliner.

Answer (score 0):

A whiteboard and a camera to capture what's on the whiteboard quickly, to be able to move on to the next thing.

Answer (score 0):

In all seriousness, when other people are involved, a whiteboard.
Later Microsoft Visio to formalize the drawings from the discussion. A former Design Director for a competitor who now works for our company routinely captures an audio recording of conferences - he uses it for his own benefit; he doesn't use it to call people out.

Answer (score 0):

[GoVisual](http://www.oreas.com/gde_en.php) is very nice free diagramming software.

Answer (score 0):

Mind mapping is really useful for this purposes. When you have distributed team, you may wan to use web-based mind mapping applications. I'm using [Mindomo](http://www.mindomo.com/) to share initial (and not only) requirements documentation with the rest of requirements management and development team.

Also I quite often use draw&scan approach to capture and share ideas, comments, schemes, etc. Often it works much better than writing a plain e-mail or doc.